# In Android Tv, How to implement the header(Navigation Drawer) where icon is always visible

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-tv, leanback

I'm working with Android TV for the first time and I'm learning to use Leanback.

In my TV App, I need to implement the Header(Navigation Drawer) where the icon should always be visible while collapsing drawer similar to **Voot Android TV App**

Reference Code https://corochann.com/browsefragment-header-customization-android-tv-application-hands-on-tutorial-17-697.html

When the focus moves to the right side, the header is collapsing fully(including title and icon). In my case, I want to collapse the header into the title and I need to show only icons in the header.

Below I have added the screenshot of Voot app for better understanding of my requirement

[Expanded Header/Navigation Drawer ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQPfn.jpg)

[Collapse Header/Navigation Drawer ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdhLM.jpg)

Comment: Hey, did you find any solution. I have the similar functionality I posted a question yesterday but have not get any ans.

Comment: Have you got solution for this? if, please share it

Comment: Does anybody have any alternative solution

Answer (score 2):

[image][image]We cannot achieve this with Leanback only. I have written a custom navigation menu fragment especially to work with RowsSupportFragment and it manages focus & selection as well.

Check out this [TVNavigationMenu](https://github.com/Arpit0492/TVNavigationMenu) repository

Comment: HI @Arpit J. I have followed your GitHub example TVNavigationMenu  i need small help I want to add fix the open drawer when we click on any navigation item can you please help me in this Thanks